# \addtocontents with list of listings

Tags: table-of-contents, listings

When I try to `\addtocontents{lst}{\string<code>}`,
no error appears, but the code does not function.

### Minimum Working Example

Note that all that all lists clearpage between
entries before and within appendices, except for
the list of listings, `lst`.

**[Note]**: Also requires creation of basic text file, `I.txt` to run.

```
\documentclass[crop=false,float=true,class=scrartcl]{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}                   % improved version of verbatim. imports script languages (with syntax coloring).
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}         % appendices. [toc adds Appendices to TOC, page adds a page listed Appendices in the document.]
\usepackage{float}                      % improves floating objects (graphics/tables).

\usepackage{color}                      % color commands.
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}         % additional color commands.

% Settings for importing scripts [listings package]
\lstset{ %
   backgroundcolor  = \color{white},     % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
   basicstyle       = \footnotesize,     % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
   breakatwhitespace= false,             % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
   breaklines       = true,              % sets automatic line breaking
   captionpos       = t,                 % sets the caption-position
   commentstyle     = \color{Green},     % comment style
   deletekeywords   = {...},             % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
   escapeinside     = {\%*}{*)},         % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
   extendedchars    = true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
   frame            = single,            % adds a frame around the code
   keepspaces       = true,              % keeps spaces in text, 
                                         %   useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
   keywordstyle     = \color{blue},      % keyword style
   language         = Matlab,            % the language of the code
   morekeywords     = {*,...},           % if you want to add more keywords to the set
   numbers          = left,              % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
   numbersep        = 5pt,               % how far the line-numbers are from the code
   numberstyle      = \tiny\color{gray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
   rulecolor        = \color{black},     % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within 
                                         %   not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
   showspaces       = false,             % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
   showstringspaces = false,             % underline spaces within strings only
   showtabs         = false,             % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
   stepnumber       = 1,                 % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
   stringstyle      = \color{purple},    % string literal style
   tabsize          = 2,                 % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
   title            = \lstname           % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption 
                                         %   instead of title
}

\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{roman}


\tableofcontents   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Contents       \vspace{-1em}} \clearpage %\addtocontents  {toc}{\string\vspace{-1em}}
\listoffigures     \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures        \vspace{-1em}} \clearpage %\addtocontents  {toc}{\string\vspace{-1em}}
\listoftables      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables         \vspace{-1em}} \clearpage %\addtocontents  {toc}{\string\vspace{-1em}}
\lstlistoflistings \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Code Listings               } \clearpage


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\section{One}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{I}  \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{II} \end{figure}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{I}  \end{table}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{II} \end{table}
\lstinputlisting[caption=I] {I.txt}
\lstinputlisting[caption=II]{I.txt}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}

\clearpage

\section{Two}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{I}  \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{II} \end{figure}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{I}  \end{table}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{II} \end{table}
\lstinputlisting[caption=I] {I.txt}
\lstinputlisting[caption=II]{I.txt}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}

\clearpage

\section{Three}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{I}  \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{II} \end{figure}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{I}  \end{table}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{II} \end{table}
\lstinputlisting[caption=I] {I.txt}
\lstinputlisting[caption=II]{I.txt}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}

\clearpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\string\clearpage}
\addtocontents{lof}{\string\clearpage}
\addtocontents{lot}{\string\clearpage}
\addtocontents{lst}{\string\clearpage}
\begin{appendices}

\clearpage

\section{A}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{I}  \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{II} \end{figure}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{I}  \end{table}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{II} \end{table}
\lstinputlisting[caption=I] {I.txt}
\lstinputlisting[caption=II]{I.txt}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}

\clearpage

\section{B}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{I}  \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{II} \end{figure}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{I}  \end{table}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{II} \end{table}
\lstinputlisting[caption=I] {I.txt}
\lstinputlisting[caption=II]{I.txt}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}

\clearpage

\section{C}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{I}  \end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H] \caption{II} \end{figure}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{I}  \end{table}
\begin{table} [H] \caption{II} \end{table}
\lstinputlisting[caption=I] {I.txt}
\lstinputlisting[caption=II]{I.txt}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}

\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\protect` instead of `\string`. The text for the table of contents is first written to the `.aux` file before it is moved to the `.toc` file. `\protect` takes care of the needed protection.

Comment: You have to use `{lol}` instead of `{lst}` in your `\addtocontents{lst}{\string<code>}` commands.

Comment: @gernot lol. ok.

Comment: @gernot: Do you want to convert your comment into an answer or shall we close this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.